# How can I add form with input type readonly field

Tags: angularjs, ejs, materialize

When I add form with second div it works properly, but not with first div

```
<div class="col s6 input-field">
    <input id="oid" type="text" value={{ioid}} class="validate" readonly ng-model="ctrl.form3.oid">
    <label for="oid">Order ID</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col s6 input-field">
    <input id="soid" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="ctrl.form3.soid">
    <label for="soid">SubOrder ID</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: it should work with 1st div also, could you provide plunkr/fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should use the `ng-value` directive here in place of the regular value attribute (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue):

```
<input id="iod" type="text" ng-value="ioid" readonly ng-model="ctrl.form3.oid">
```

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/klUj1xbk6txHAnQdFrFK?p=preview